# Geoprocessing tools are not opening?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

When double clicked on tools of arctoolbox, no dialog box is opening, for the "buffer" or "intersect", or for any of the tools in the ArcToolBox.

I faced the same problem in both ArcGIS version 10.5 and 10.6.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend deleting your default map template, called **Normal.mxt**. What can often happen (especially if you're regularly switching displays on a laptop/extra screen/projector) is the tools open, but they open off-screen. This location that they open in is saved in your map template, and is not easy to fix within ArcMap.

If you're in Windows 10, close ArcMap/Catalog, and navigate to:

```
c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.X\ArcMap\Templates
```

There should be a file called **Normal.mxt** in that folder. Delete it, or move it to a backup location. When you restart ArcMap, a new version of the file is created, which should reset the UI to factory default, and tools should open in the main ArcMap window.

A more thorough walk-through of the process and other fundamentals on template/UI customization is [found here on ESRI's site](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/about-configuring-the-user-interface.htm#GUID-05829A46-1765-4A44-9F35-8CC06E2D4D07).

Answer (score 0):

If you face same problem in ArcGIS Pro then check your

> PythonPath

environment variable. Remove the redundant entry of path and it will work.